# Recommendations for places where I can get good css designs/ web 2.0ish buttons, tables, etc

Tags: html, css, resources

Im designing a website, and often I need to present information in a nice table, or need a nice button, etc...

I need recommendations for any websites which have a large collection of these elements which I could just use, instead of designing my own.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Edited to add much more resources:

The most [**important resource ever**](http://www.google.com).
Google is your friend, use it.
All of those resources were found using [google](http://www.google.com).

**Generators:**
[Creatr logo generator](http://creatr.cc)
[Templatr template generator](http://templatr.cc/)
[50 Useful generators for css development](http://speckyboy.com/2009/07/15/50-useful-tools-and-generators-for-easy-css-development/)
[Button generator](http://www.buttongenerator.com/index.php)
[CSS Menu Maker](http://www.cssmenumaker.com/)
[Color palette generatpr](http://www.degraeve.com/color-palette/index.php)
[Dotemplate template generator](http://www.dotemplate.com/)
[RSS & other validated graphic buttons generator](http://www.feedforall.com/public/rss-graphic-tool.htm)
[Generateit - lots of useful generators](http://www.generateit.net/index.htm)
[Lorem Ipsum generator](http://www.lipsum.com/)
[GenerateIt - All kinds of generators, very recommended](http://www.generateit.net/index.htm)
[13Styles menu generator](http://13styles.com/category/css-menus/)

**Graphics:**
[Lost and found web blog](http://lostandtaken.com/)
[Bittbox freebies](http://www.bittbox.com/category/freebies/)
[Open Graphic Design](http://opengraphicdesign.com/)
[Famfamfam.com - free icons.](http://famfamfam.com/)
[Freeiconsweb - as phonix suggested](http://www.freeiconsweb.com/)
**[FindIcon.com](http://findicons.com/) - huge collection, over 200,000 free icons for the web**

**CSS Templates**
[Code sucks](http://www.code-sucks.com/css%20layouts/)
[CSSZenGarden](http://www.csszengarden.com/)
[Max Design page layouts](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/presentation/page_layouts/)
[Layout gallery](http://blog.html.it/layoutgala/)
[Blue Robot layouts](http://www.bluerobot.com/web/layouts/)
[Dynamic Drive css library](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/layouts/category/C11/)
[Smashing magazine - free templates and layouts](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/01/12/free-css-layouts-and-templates/)
[CSSPlay](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/)

**Templates:**
[Andreas Viklund's template page](http://andreasviklund.com/templates/)
[45 Free templates](http://dzineblog.com/2008/07/45-excellent-free-web-templates.html)
[Template Monster](http://www.templatemonster.com/)
[Templates.com](http://www.templates.com/)
[Freewebsitetemplates.com](http://www.freewebsitetemplates.com/)
[Templates Box](http://www.templatesbox.com/)
[OSWD - as Paul Janaway suggested](http://www.oswd.org/)
[Styleshout - check the resources page as well](http://www.styleshout.com/)
[CSS Portal](http://www.cssportal.com/css-templates/)
[TemplateFusion](http://templatefusion.org/?cat=3)

**Online Magazines:**
[Smashing magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/)

Comment: thank you very much.
I will be adding more from time to time :)

Answer (score 3):

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/

Smashing magazine is a fantastic place to pick Web UI related tips/tricks/designs. You MUST browse older articles as there are host of icon sets, UI designs and examples. I would strongly recommend it. :)

Answer (score 2):

http://www.freeiconsweb.com/

Answer (score 1):

http://graphicriver.net 
If you are not looking at only free stuff, this site has some great icons, buttons, graphics which you can purchase at low reasonable prices (about 2-5USD per set).

Answer (score 1):

Hope these will help you in some way. :)

http://www.oswd.org/

2080 free designs

Answer (score 0):

[This is](http://www.smashingmagazine.com) a non profile provider Please try this.

But more impotent what I think designing is what we create, Try to have your won Idea first.