# Frameworks/templates for web developer

Tags: html, css, templates

I'm C/C++, Java developer and now in order to put some variety into my work, I decided to start playing with web development - i'm using django. However, I'm hopeless with graphics and advanced css. I would like to build and ship some apps with elegant and simple design. Are there any frameworks/templates which let me build something great looking without photoshop skills?

I'm looking for something useful like: http://960.gs.

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036696/recommendations-for-places-where-i-can-get-good-css-designs-web-2-0ish-buttons/1042475#1042475
This is a dup, please close

Comment: @the_drow: The linked answer may be on point, but the question is most certainly not an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

[Tacit](https://yegor256.github.io/tacit/) CSS framework would be very in-line with what you're searching:

> I'm hopeless with graphics and advanced css. I would like to build and ship some apps with elegant and simple design.

You include the library on your HTML pages and it will give the page a tidy and modern look by default, without the need to define classes to HTML elements or do any CSS code.

Here is an example of [my personal page](http://filfreire.com). Only CSS work I had to do was the inclusion of [Tacit](https://yegor256.github.io/tacit/), and the page gets that look, working both on Desktop and on Mobile.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.freecsstemplates.org/

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://responsive.vermilion.com/compare.php) you can find a nice comparison about responsive frameworks. In my personal experience, I've worked with Twitter Bootstrap on several projects and like it. Since I've used the other frameworks so extensively I cannot (or should not) say it's the best, but at least it fits my requirements and I find pleasing to work with it.
There's a lot of projects integrating these UI frameworks with web frameworks like Django or Rails.

With a simple web search you'll find a lot of themes (free and paid ones), pick what best fits your needs.